# Git change author name/email in a long ago commit in team repo

Tags: git, github

Before I create this question, i have already read the answer using `git filter-branch export` and `git rebase` but none of them would be applicable to my situation here.

So I've joined the company for 3 months, the first commit that I made on the repo was under the computer name and email (Unknown/something@something) and that's the only commit with that name and email. Now that email starts causing us trouble when we setup new job in Jenkin, it starts sending email to that address which causes a bounced back email for everyone.

I would like to change the name and email at that specific commit to my own, so that I can eliminate the problem.  However, the problem is:

- It's a team repo, I cannot use filter-branch to reset all emails and name.
- That commit is now thousands commits behind HEAD, I cannot manually do rebase.
- There are some active branches right off master after that commit and they haven't been merged yet.

I'm really looking for a solution to change the author's name and email of just that specific commit only, and also wouldn't affect anyone else. Please help. Thank you and really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my final solution that I just did:

- Have everyone working on that branch commit and merge their work back to the branch.
- Save a copy of that latest commit to local machine.
- Roll back the branch to the commit right before the commit that I want to change the info.
- Hard copy the local copy and overwrite the code that I just roll back to.
- Make that as the latest commit.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

If you change anything about a commit, even a single character or bit, you get a new, different commit.  If there are many "downstream" commits—commits that have the original "wrong" commit as a parent, grand-parent, great-grand-parent, etc., somewhere in their ancestry—then each of those commits requires copying to a new, different commit ID as well, because each one lists its parent IDs and those parent IDs will change as you go through your repository updating parent IDs.

This is what's behind git's claim to "strong data integrity" means: you *can't* change history without changing all the SHA-1s from that point onward, i.e., copying all the old commits to new ones.  This is considered a feature, except of course when you're trying to fix some ancillary data (like a misspelled or wrong user name) in a commit. :-)

What you *can* do, which may or may not be helpful, is to use something like git's "notes" feature to attach additional ancillary data to a commit, without modifying the commit itself.  The way notes work is that programs that examine commits—such as `git log`—first read the commit itself by commit SHA-1 ID, then use that ID as (part of) a key to see if someone wants something else noted about that comment.  The "something else" can be changed, even though the SHA-1 ID can't.

The problem with this method is that you must look at the secondary data.  If you're using `git log`, it will by default look for the notes listed in `core.notesRef`, which in turn defaults to `refs/notes/commits`.  If you're using something else, who knows?

Answer (score 2):

> I have already read the answer using git filter-branch export and **git rebase** but none of them would be applicable to my situation here.

Actually, I believe your best option here is to do a `git rebase` in interactive mode.  If the troublesome commit in question happened 1000 commits from the current `HEAD` of your branch, then you would type:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~1000
```

You can edit the message before committing, then continue with the rebase.  The rebase itself would likely be less painful than you think, since you are not actually touching the code itself.  Actually, the remaining 999 or so commits should proceed with no conflict at all.

> I'm really looking for a solution to change the author's name and email of just that specific commit only, and also wouldn't affect anyone else.

Unfortunately, you can't do this without affecting everyone else.  By changing the message of the commit in question, you are also rewriting history.  This means you will have to force push the branch to the remote.  In the process of doing this, you could throw off or surprise all other uses currently working on this branch.

So here is what I suggest:

- Have the team commit all their work on the branch containing the bad email commit (and they must not touch the branch until you complete the next step)
- You can then pull the branch, perform the interactive rebase, and force push to the remote
- The rest of the team will then **delete** (yes, you read right) their local copy of this branch
- Finally, the team will pull the corrected branch from the remote

If you follow these steps, I believe you can eliminate this email comment problem with minimal pain.

Comment: thank for the solution, but there are some branches that branches off from this branch and are still actively being developed, any effects that you can think of when doing the interactive rebase?

Comment: Is there any chance you can also rebase the branches?  How many do you have?  If you really want that commit changed, you are going to have to rewrite history, there is no way around it AFAIK.

Comment: `git filter-branch` will do the job that otherwise requires multiple careful `git rebase`s.  You can construct your filter so that it affects just the one commit.  In either case you'll wind up re-ID-ing all of the subsequent commits, though.

Comment: @torek Good point about all subsequent commits.  There really is no easy to do this IMO.

Comment: Thank all for your answer, so far I will try with this approach.

Comment: @Kiddo Please pay attention to Torek's comment about using `filter-branch` instead of `git rebase`; this could save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your solution is to use [git replace](https://git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/17/replace.html) to replace one commit by another one in the history.

1. Create a branch on your problematic commit
2. Amend the commit (not sure if it change the author. Otherwise you will have to recreate the commit entirely using a trick to overwrite current date `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2000-01-01T12:00:00" git commit --date==2000-01-01T12:00:00`)
3. Use git replace to replace the old commit with the new one
4. Hope that jenkins understand git replace. If so, it's finished (quickly easy). The Added value of this solution is really here.
5. If not, use git filter-branch but it will impact everyone history (like the other solutions proposed) and other devs will hate you (but this solution is much more safe than pure rebase!)